# Cannot figure out how to get Circle class to work

Tags: java, swing, geometry

My current assignment in a beginning Java course is to animate a circle across the window. The problem I am having is that no matter what I put when I want to create a circle or rectangle, or anything like that, I always get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"
```

After Googling, I always find that the answer is that I am missing the 'public static void main' code, but I have it included every single time. Even simple code such as this (which sinec I have yet to see how rectangles or circles actually would appear I'm assuming this code should be correct):

```
public class Chapter6_Hw4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);
        System.out.println( "You have created a rectangle" );
    }
}
```

Hope I can get some help on this from you guys. I'm assuming this is just some really noobie issue I'm overlooking. Thanks!

Comment: Should there be a blank constructor? `Chapter6_Hw4(){ }`

Comment: @Adel: what for, no object instance of that class is created. (The class itself is instantiated, but that doesn't need a constructor.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure that you're compiling and running `Chapter6_Hw4.java`, not `Rectangle.java`.

Comment: Yep it was a noobie issue. I had another file opened in JCreator I wasn't paying attention and I was pressing run for the entire workspace. Doh! >.<

Comment: Glad I could help.  Don't forget to accept the answer so everyone else knows that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

Check the file name of the java file. It should match your public classname..
In your case
"Chapter6_Hw4.java"